# Is ASMedia ASM1061 SATA3 Controller supported under Linux ?

Tags: linux

Is ASMedia ASM1061 supported under Linux ? 
I have an AsRock 880GMH/U3S3 motherboard but i can’t get the SATA3 controller to work. 
There are some spare info around google about it, but nothing that fully confirms the support, the official drivers don't support linux either.
Anyone managed to make this work ?

Comment: For ASM1062: Works well with Debian 11 and Linux kernel 5.10. ASM1062 also recognizes hot plugged disks on ports which were disconnected during boot (unlike the SATA chipset of my motherboard).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some trial and error, I managed to make it work. First of all, I upgraded my kernel to the Debian backports version (2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64), then I had set the mode of the controller to AHCI and afterwards, it was detected at boot time. I hope it's stable and has no problems.

After a few days I can confirm that it's stable and that I had no issues with it. Transfer speed seems fine.

Comment: Setting the controller mode (in 2 places) to AHCI worked for Linux Mint 12 as well. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, could you please add the kernel config option that you enabled (as a one liner `.config` file entry , or path in ncurces `menuconfig`). Thank you

Comment: How died you set the controller mode to AHCI?

Answer (score 7):

[kernel commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=c9703765f3d5ab27909011dee4a05affe48e4442).
works perfect for me (tested in 3.7.8)

Comment: More information on what this is doing would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It very buggy in Linux kernel 4.*. It's 2018 and with a brand new Asrock MB that uses this driver. Horrible experience with ATA errors.

**UPDATE**: I have learned that it's the two ports that use ASMedia drivers. The other 4 standard SATA ports are good. *It is vert confusing with the port layout but the 2 ASMedia ports sit in the middle of the normal SATA ports* and they are best left unused.

If you have to use the 2 ASMedia ports then disable the NCQ command and this will fix the issue that I have had...but at the cost of some performance.

Comment: same here, don't downvote.

Comment: I have learned that it's the two ports that use ASMedia drivers. The other 4 standard SATA ports are good. It is vert confusing with the port layout but the 2 ASMedia ports sit in the middle of the normal SATA ports and they are best left unused.

Answer (score 0):

This took a lot of time to understand, but in fact the ASMedia ASM1061 works well with Linux... as long you do not connect a SATA DVD drive!

If you do it, the kernel boot freezes with the message "AHCI controller unavailable!". Tested with Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and 19.10 alpha.